# Jquery Back button does not work

Tags: jquery-mobile, onclick

**index.html**:

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
      <html>
        <head>
          <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
          <title>Untitled Document</title>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
          <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
          <div data-role="page" id="reviewsPage">
            <script language="text/javascript">
              /* VERY IMPORTANT this is before loading jquery.mobile JS */
              $(document).on("mobileinit", function() {
              // Make your jQuery Mobile framework configuration changes here!


              });

            </script>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
              $(document).on("pagebeforeshow", function(event) {
                $("#mybtn").bind("click", function(e) {
                  $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg();
                  $.mobile.changePage("twitter.html", {
                  reloadPage: false, changeHash: true,
                });
              });
            });

            </script>
            <div data-role="header">
              <h1>Reviews</h1>
              <a href="#" id="mybtn" class="ui-btn-right" >TWEET</a>
            </div>
          </div>
          </body>
          </html>
```

**tweet.html**:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>

    <div data-role="page" id="twitterPage"  >
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on("mobileinit", function() {
        });

        $(document).bind('pageshow', '#twitterPage', function(event, ui) {
            $(document).on('click', '[data-rel=back]', function() {
            $.mobile.changePage('index.html');
        });
        });
      </script>

      <div data-role="header" data-add-back-btn="true" data-back-btn-text="Previous" >
          <a href="#" id="k" data-rel="back" data-icon="arrow-l">Back</a>
          <a href="index.html" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" data-direction="reverse">Home</a>
      </div>
      <div data-role="content">
        <ul id="tweet-list" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
          <li data-role="list-divider">
            <p>
              Tweets
            </p>
          </li>
        </ul> 
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here I have link when the link is clicked **tweet.html** file will be called. But when I clicked the back button I will be directed to the previous page without any error. But second time onwards when I click the back button I will be directed to the previous page and comes to the current page again.

Comment: What is the previous page? Does it have code that links to this page?

Comment: previous page is index.html second page=tweet.html

Comment: `data-add-back-btn="true"` should be added to `<div data-role="page">` and it wont work when ajax if disabled. Plus, using `$.mobile.changePage()` and `data-add-back-btn="true"` will result in an error. So you either use `$.mobile.changePage()` or never use it.

Comment: Actually i cant do that using browser back button.Just See my update

Comment: if still want to use `$.mobile.changePage()`, you can do it `$(document).on('click', '[data-rel=back]', function() { $.mobile.changePage('index.html'); });`

Comment: Hey i tried .still got nothing .It.Just see my update and see weather i did correctly

Comment: do you get any error?

Comment: i do not get any error but i can go the previous page.It only works very first time

Comment: tweets.html has no jQM js library?

Comment: I change it see mu update still got same problem

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#mybtn").unbind();`
```

unbind event will prevent this